# How do I add a UISegmentedControl to my UIToolbar using Storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol

1. I'm trying to add a Segmented Control to my UIToolbar below, but when I try to drag it over in Storyboard it replaces my Table View.
2. Also, when I try to add UIBarButton to my Toolbar it pushes my Prototype Cells down... do I have my views hierarchy wrong?
3. When I add a UIBarButton item anyway, in the simulator the toolbar is not Black Transparent as I set in my navigation control inspector. Whats up with that?

thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Didn't read the question properly, sorry.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Do it programmatically. You need to assign a frame to your UIToolbar first, then you can add elements in it (the segmentedControl). I suggest though to use `UIBarButtonItems`, which basically are the same.

To stick it to the bottom, try to do this way:

```
#define SCREEN_FRAME [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 44, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 44);
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height-toolBar.frame.size.height,SCREEN_FRAME.size.width,toolBar.frame.size.height);

//Setting up the items

UIBarButtonItem *first = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourAction:)] autorelease]; 
UIBarButtonItem *second = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourAction:)] autorelease]; 

//Creating an array with the items
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first,second, nil];

//Assigning the array to the toolBar
[toolBar setItems: items];
```

Then you can set its style with

```
mytoolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

2 - Same as above, framing.

3 - You need to set your navigationController style to Black.
Use `self.navigationController.navigationBar.style = UIBarStyleBlack`; ,or in IB choose the buttons and from Inspector set Tint or Style to whatever you want.

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958956/how-to-add-a-uitoolbar-to-a-uitableviewcontroller-programmatically) question

Comment: how do i make it always stick to the bottom of the screen? right now it scrolls as the table scrolls

Comment: Hmm, its still not sticking to bottom? I'm adding the toolbar to the view like this:    

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

Comment: Are you using a UITableView? If so `[self.tableView addSubview:toolbar];`

Comment: tried that and still doesn't work..  Yup using table view. I think dragging a TVController in storyboard automatically creates a TV.

Comment: Yes it does, try to set an outlet for it too. `IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;`

Comment: says table view already inherited from UITableViewController... also when I add the linne for toolbar.frame = ... the toolbar loads below the initial screen (I have to scroll down to see it)

Comment: That's because it is declared below, as a subView of the view.. try tweaking a bit with the frame

Comment: Ok i added it to navigationController view and it works!      [self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];

Answer (score 7):

To create *Segmented Control* element in the toolbar with *Interface builder* it is possible to use the following hint

1) Create *Segmented Control Bar Button Item* in Navigation Controller:

[image: Create Segmented Control Bar Button Item in Navigation Controller]

2) Drag *Bar Button Item* up to Navigation Item

[image: Drag Bar Button Item up to Navigation Item]

3) Then you should get the following structure

[image: The resulting structure]

4) Now you can select *Segmented Control* to set its properties

[image: Select Segmented Control to set its properties]

Answer (score 1):

I presume there's a navigation view controller somewhere in here.  They have their own toolbar, but it's hidden and empty.  The toolbar you're seeing is just a simulation of a toolbar for the purpose of letting you edit the UI.

So to do this with storyboard, don't add the segmented control to the simulated toolbar, create a new toolbar and add it to the tree of views available in your controller (as a sibling to your Table View) and create an IBOutlet to reference it.  Then in your viewDidLoad method assign the items in the toolbar to the toolbar already created by the view controller.

In this example I've created a property on my view controller called (cunningly) toolbar:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar toolbar;
```

In my view controller's implementation I assign the toolbar items manually:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [self setToolbarItems:self.toolbar.items animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

You'll need to hide the toolbar when the view controller is popped, for instance in the calling view controller:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Assuming you want to hide it, of course.

Comment: Undeleted and edited this answer, as I think it's still relevant.

Comment: When I add it as a sibling it doesn't actually show either in the storyboard or in the simulator.. is it being hidden by the table view?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't show anywhere.  But you can still reference the IBOutlet - it's just a convenience so you don't have to create the items and the array in the code. Then if you use the code I've given the items will appear in the controller's default toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

I did this by placing the UISegmentedController in a Bar Button Item.

Add a toolbar to the UINavigationController window, then enable the display of this toolbar on a ViewController screen.

Drag a bar button into the toolbar on the ViewController screen, and drag a UISegmentedController into that (resizing the button to the full width of the screen)

To wire it all up, ctrl-drag from the UISegmentedController to the corresponding .h file, drag from "referencing outlet" to the yellow view controller icon (using the same variable name), then drag from "ValueChanged" to the yellow icon (selecting the method on the controller that you want to call on a new selection).

This all seems to work as expected. (If you can't select a segment on the controller to set an initial value, you didn't connect up the referencing outlet as described above. That stumped me for a little while.)