# How to insert UISegmentedControl to UITableViewController in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uistoryboard, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using Storyboards, and am interested in inserting a UISegmentedControl in my UITableView controller as such:

[image]

When I try to drag one directly from the object list, I can't manage to insert on top of the `tableView` above the search bar and below the nav bar. I also didn't have any luck dragging it into the view hierarchy panel on the left. I have looked into doing it programmatically as [suggested by this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072452/how-do-i-add-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-my-uitoolbar-using-storyboard), but do not want the segmented control to be inside the Nav Bar, but rather still in the `tableView`.  How may I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the XIB, you need to have an underlying UIView with the UISegcontrol, the search bar,  and tableviews as subviews.

Comment: Thanks Paulo. So you are saying that instead of using an underlying UITableViewController, I should have a regular UIViewController with UISegementedControl and the rest?

Comment: Yes  that is what you need to do!