# Add toolbar to the left side of an UISplittview

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, toolbar

How can I add a toolbar on the left side of the splittview?
I have a navigationcontroller
and i already tried this:

> UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init]; toolbar.barStyle =
>   UIBarStyleDefault;
>
> [toolbar sizeToFit];
>
> UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
>                                  initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
>   action:@selector(info_clicked:)];
>
> [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButton,nil]];
>
> [self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];

But it is noch working. It appears at the top and not at the bottom

MEMA

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958956/how-to-add-a-uitoolbar-to-a-uitableviewcontroller-programmatically This may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create your own toolbar for a UINavigationController, just set `toolbarHidden` to `NO` to use its built-in one and add your `UIBarButtonItem` to it.